# What is difference between with and env

Tags: github-actions

I am new to github actions, and I see two things used for configuring the steps (correct me if i am wrong), `with` and `env`.

What is the difference between these two and how they are used.

```
uses: someAction
with:
  x: 10
  y: 20
env:
  x1: 30
  y2: 40
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

with - is specifically used for passing parameters to the action

env - is used specifically for introducing environment variables that can be accessed depending on scope of the resource

```
  workflow envs - can be accessed by all resources in the workflow except services
  
  job envs - can be accessed by all resources under job except services
  
  step envs - can be accessed by any resource within the step
```

Here is an example on how parameters are handled

Let's say an action is created with following parameter in `action.yaml`

```
name: 'Npm Audit Action'
inputs:
  dirPath:
    description: 'Directory path of the project to audit'
    required: true
    default: './'
```

Then we will provide this parameter through the `with` tag in our workflow

```
- name: Use the action
  uses: meroware/npm-audit-action@v1.0.2
  with:
    dirPath: vulnerable-project
```

Then in the action code we would handle it as such if building a Node.js action

```
const core = require("@actions/core");
const dirPath = core.getInput("dirPath");
```

Envs within actions are accessed differently, let's say we are building a Node.js action, then we would access it through `process.env`. Going back to our example action

```
name: 'Npm Audit Action'
env:
   SOME_ENV: 'hey I am an env'
```

Then this could be accessed as

```
const { someEnv: SOME_ENV } = process.env
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see [in the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-11) `with:` used to define a variable.

While env defines an [`environmnent` variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/using-environment-variables), as [defined here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env) and in [`jobs.<job_id>.env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenv)

> - an environment variable defined in a step will override job and workflow variables with the same name, while the step executes.
> - A variable defined for a job will override a workflow variable with the same name, while the job executes.

You need both to [access secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow):

```
steps:
  - name: Hello world action
    with: # Set the secret as an input
      super_secret: ${{ secrets.SuperSecret }}
    env: # Or as an environment variable
      super_secret: ${{ secrets.SuperSecret }}
```